# Creating a Thymeleaf layout for <body>, which can be customized for each individual template

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am developing an app with Spring Boot/MVC and use Thymeleaf v3.1.1 templates for views.

There are common elements in each template:

- Head > Stylesheets
- Body > navbar, footer, JS scripts (at the end of body)

Not to repeat the common elements for each template, I have created below layout. I converted the **body** into a fragment and within the body fragment, in addition to the navbar and so on, I have created a **content** fragment to be replaced by individual content.

Layout is successfully integrated; I can see the navbar and footer in the templates.

However, **I am unable to replace the th:fragment="content" with an individual page's content.**

The layout I am using is > **layout.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head th:fragment="head">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title th:text="${title}">Title</title>
    <th:block th:insert="~{fragments/bootstrap :: bootstrap-css}"></th:block>
    <th:block th:insert="~{fragments/bootstrap :: bootstrap-icons}"></th:block>
</head>

<body th:fragment="body">
<th:block th:insert="~{fragments/navbar :: navbar}"></th:block>

<div th:fragment="content"></div>

<footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">© 2023 All rights reserved.</span>
    </div>
</footer>

<th:block th:insert="~{fragments/bootstrap :: bootstrap-js}"></th:block>
</body>
</html>
```

And an example template is > **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head th:replace="~{layout :: head(title='Homepage')}"></head>

<body th:replace="~{layout :: body}">
<div th:replace="~{layout :: content}" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 text-center">
            <h1 class="mb-5">Welcome to App</h1>
            <a th:href="@{/register/customer}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Register</a>
            <a th:href="@{/login}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</a><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Apparently, body is completely replaced by the layout's body and even though I created a div with `th:replace="~{layout :: content}"` it is not working.

I have checked official documentation here, but they don't mention such a case: [Thymeleaf Layout](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout)

Any ideas sers?

Comment: Have you checked out layout-dialect? https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html#thymeleaf-layout-dialect https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Ultraq's layout dialect worked :) I wanted to make it work with the official Thymeleaf implementation, but had to turn back to this layout-dialect